# how to disable some rows in a list shown in Android dialog box

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I am having to display a dialog box which contains some list of items.it has list of items and a checkbox.
User can select one or multiple items . On click of OK, the selected items is stored into Array.

Upon opening the dialog box again, I want to disable the previously selected items and make it grey out or non-selectable.

So second time, the dialog box should show all items but the previously selected items should be greyed out.

How to achieve this feature. I feel, i can search the array of selected items, but I want help on the UI side to show disabled or grey out of the items in the list shown in the dialog box

Answer (score 0):

```
View getView(){
    // blah blah + inflating view
    if( isItemSelected(position) ){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
    }
    // more blah blah
    return view
}
```

You can use the [`setBackgroundColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) to set the view to a grey-ish color.

> Sets the background color for this view.

Also have a look at [`isEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) method of the `BaseAdapter` class.